# How to add php into inline style background-image Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to include image path to background-image in Wordpress correctly? Cause this isn't working for me

```
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url("<php bloginfo('template_url'); ?> /assets/img/slide1.jpg");">
```

[Screen of code from inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc6Q3.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying it in a wrong way. Reference : [Check Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/)

Replace your code with:

```
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/slide1.jpg');">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure u didn't mess with your theme options? because that thing should just work. Check the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/

It is noted to use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead for the parent template directory or `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` for the child template directory